# Symfony2 Unrecognized option "providers" under "security.providers.chain_provider"

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Guys i have this problem when trying to "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" i don't know how to solve it(Unrecognized option "providers" under "security.providers.chain_provider")

this is my security.yml

```
security:

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

encoders:
    Setsuna\PrivateBundle\Entity\User: sha512
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~
    fr3d_ldapbundle:
        id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
    chain_provider:
        providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        fr3d_ldap: ~
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path: /profile
        logout: true
        anonymous: true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used chained providers but [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/multiple_user_providers.html) shows that the config looks like different than yours:

```
security:
    providers:
        chain_provider:
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    foo: { password: test }
        user_db:
            entity: { class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User, property: username }
```